# Cannot do simple initialization of variable - 'data type not understood'

Tags: tensorflow

I was running through the CIFAR-10 tutorial on Tensorflow, but I cannot get any of my variable declarations to work. Even something simple as:

```
biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
```

gives the error:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-86228512ca30> in <module>()
----> 1 biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

/home/mmm/programs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in get_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape)
    730       initializer=initializer, regularizer=regularizer, trainable=trainable,
    731       collections=collections, caching_device=caching_device,
--> 732       partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape)
    733 
    734 

/home/mmm/programs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in get_variable(self, var_store, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape)
    594           regularizer=regularizer, reuse=self.reuse, trainable=trainable,
    595           collections=collections, caching_device=caching_device,
--> 596           partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape)
    597 
    598   def _get_partitioned_variable(

/home/mmm/programs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in get_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape)
    159         initializer=initializer, regularizer=regularizer, reuse=reuse,
    160         trainable=trainable, collections=collections,
--> 161         caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
    162 
    163   def _get_partitioned_variable(

/home/mmm/programs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in _get_single_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, validate_shape)
    423 
    424     should_check = reuse is not None
--> 425     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype)
    426     shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(shape)
    427 

/home/mmm/programs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.pyc in as_dtype(type_value)
    534 
    535   for key, val in _NP_TO_TF:
--> 536     if key == type_value:
    537       return val
    538 

TypeError: data type not understood
```

I am desperate to find out what is wrong and where it went wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you checked documentation - This should have been your first thing before posting here. Change your code to `biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [64], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))`

Comment: I did check the documentation. I am new to python so I did not know the necessity of using keyword arguments until bradden_gross kindly pointed out the fix.

Comment: @gwtw14 I agree this is really confusing to me too. The tutorial seems to suggest that one has to pass them as in the example but one actually has to be explicit on the name of the argument. That was annoying. Thanks for asking the question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tutorial but it looks like you provided tf.constant_initializer(0.0) as your data type which returns an initializer to generate constants. The third parameter of tf.get_variable() should be the data type of your variable which for a biases variable is usually something like tf.float32 or tf.float64.

Comment: Thank you!! I am new to python so I didn't realize there was a distinction/need for keyword arguments vs. positional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation also put me off. I just want to be more explicit for future readers.

The [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#understanding-tf-get-variable) has

```
`tf.get_variable(<name>, <shape>, <initializer>)`: Creates or returns a variable with a given name.
```

which gave the suggestion that maybe just passing 3 things would work. Wrong. Need to be explicit on the key word argument. So the following won't work:

```
def get_mdl_get_var(x):
    # variables for parameters
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [784, 10], tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [10], tf.constant_initializer(value=0.1))
    Wx_b = tf.matmul(x, W)+b
    y = tf.nn.softmax(Wx_b)
    return y
```

but the following code works now:

```
def get_mdl_get_var(x):
    # variables for parameters
    W = tf.get_variable(name='W', shape=[784, 10], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.get_variable(name='b', shape=[10], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.1))
    Wx_b = tf.matmul(x, W)+b
    y = tf.nn.softmax(Wx_b)
    return y
```

hope it helps.